# Python Flask MySQL commit will insert, will not update

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python, flask-wtforms

I can insert, but I cannot update.  Excerpts from code:

app/models.py

```
class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "my_locations"
    loc_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    loc_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    loc_detail = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    loc_postal_code = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('loc_name', 'loc_detail', name='_location_name_detail_uc'),
            )
```

app/forms.py

```
class LocationForm(FlaskForm):
    loc_id = IntegerField('Loc ID')
    loc_name = StringField('Name' , validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max=50)])
    loc_detail = StringField('Detail', validators=[Length(max=50), Optional()])
    loc_postal_code = StringField('Postal Code', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=10)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

app/routes.py

```
@app.route('/edit_location/<string:loc_id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit_location(loc_id):
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    if loc_id == "0":
        # Empty form
        title_sub = "Add"
        form = LocationForm(loc_id=loc_id)
        # form.loc_id = loc_id
    else:
        # Populated form
        title_sub = "Edit"
        location = Location.query.filter_by(loc_id=loc_id).first()

        form = LocationForm(loc_id=location.loc_id, \
                            loc_name=location.loc_name, \
                            loc_detail=location.loc_detail, \
                            loc_postal_code=location.loc_postal_code
                           )

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            location = Location(loc_id=form.loc_id.data, \
                                loc_name=form.loc_name.data, \
                                loc_detail=form.loc_detail.data, \
                                loc_postal_code=form.loc_postal_code.data
                               )

            logging.info("edit_location(): location:" + str(location.loc_postal_code))
            if location.loc_detail:
                loc_str = location.loc_name + ', ' + location.loc_detail
            else:
                loc_str = location.loc_name

            if loc_id == "0":
                db.session.add(location)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Location (' + loc_str + ') added.', 'success')
            else:
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Location (' + loc_str + ') updated.', 'success')

            return redirect(url_for('location'))

        except IntegrityError:
            logging.error("edit_location(): Intg Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
            db.session.rollback()
            flash('Location (' + loc_str + ') already exists.', 'error')

        except DatabaseError:
            logging.error("edit_location(): DB Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
            db.session.rollback()
        except Exception as e:
            flash('Error in form, site administrators have been notified. We apologize for the inconvenience.', 'error')
            logging.error("edit_location(): Exception occurred", exc_info=True)

    return render_template('edit_location.html', title=title_sub + " Location", loc_id=loc_id, form=form)
```

app/templates/edit_location.html

```
{% extends "main_page.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="edit-location">
  <div class="page-header">
      <h2>{% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock %}</h2>
  </div>

  {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
  <form method=post name="editLocationForm" action="{{ url_for('edit_location', loc_id=form.loc_id.data) }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <input type="hidden" name="loc_id" value="{{ form.loc_id.data }}">
    <table>
        <tr>{{ render_field(form.loc_name) }} </tr>
        <tr>{{ render_field(form.loc_detail) }}</tr>
        <tr>{{ render_field(form.loc_postal_code) }}</tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><small id="locDetail" class="form-text text-muted">e.g.: Rink A, Field #2, West Court</small></td>
              </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="document.editLocationForm.submit();" role="button"> <span>&check;</span> Submit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('location') }}" role="button"> <span>&times;</span> Cancel</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>

    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I insert using `edit_locations`, my `loc_id` = 0, and the MySQL commit works as expected.
When I update, I'm following a link like `/edit_locations/5` or `/edit_locations/293`.  The form pre-populates as expected, I update the loc_postal_code, but when I click **Submit** it does not update the record on the backend.
I can see the new `loc_postal_code` in the log, so I know the new value exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit your code according to the sample code block that I sent, the problem you want will be solved.

```
form = LocationForm(request.form)
if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
    try:
        if loc_id == "0":
            # Add
            location = Location(loc_id=form.loc_id.data,
                                loc_name=form.loc_name.data,
                                loc_detail=form.loc_detail.data,
                                loc_postal_code=form.loc_postal_code.data)

        else:
            # Update
            location = Location.query.filter(Location.loc_id == loc_id).first()

            location.loc_name = form.loc_name.data
            location.loc_detail = form.loc_detail.data
            location.loc_postal_code = form.loc_postal_code.data

        db.session.add(location)
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        # Exceptions
        logging.error("...")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I suppose I should have mentioned that I tried that already, in which case I get an IntegrityError due to duplicate entries:
```sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError) 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'```

Comment: Sorry i missed this point,  you need to update columns you want to before commit. `location.loc_name = form.loc_name.data ... `

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing right after the if method=POST and try: “location = Location(loc_id=form.loc_id.data, \”... etc.

Comment: What you do inserts new rows. To update, you must do something like this:
`location = Location.query.filter_by(loc_id=loc_id).first()

location.loc_name=form.loc_name.data
location.loc_detail=form.loc_detail.data
location.loc_postal_code=form.loc_postal_code.data

db.session.add(location)
db.session.commit()`

Comment: See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_orm_updating_objects.htm

Comment: When I include ```db.session.add(location)``` I get the IntegrityError exception due to the unique constraint.

Comment: I updated the my answer and sent a sample code snippet. Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @user11527247!

Here's what I ultimately did in routes.py:

```
@app.route('/edit_location/<int:loc_id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit_location(loc_id):
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    if request.method == "GET":
        if loc_id == 0:
            # Empty form
            title_sub = "Add"
            form = LocationForm(request.form)
            form.loc_id = loc_id
        else:
            # Populated form
            title_sub = "Edit"
            location = Location.query.filter_by(loc_id=loc_id).first()
            form = LocationForm(loc_id=location.loc_id, \
                            loc_name=location.loc_name, \
                            loc_detail=location.loc_detail, \
                            loc_postal_code=location.loc_postal_code
                           )
    else:
        form = LocationForm(request.form)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            if loc_id == 0:
                location = Location(loc_id=form.loc_id.data, \
                                loc_name=form.loc_name.data, \
                                loc_detail=form.loc_detail.data, \
                                loc_postal_code=form.loc_postal_code.data
                               )
            else:
                location = Location.query.filter_by(loc_id=loc_id).first()

                location.loc_id = form.loc_id.data
                location.loc_name = form.loc_name.data
                location.loc_detail = form.loc_detail.data
                location.loc_postal_code = form.loc_postal_code.data

                if location.loc_detail:
                    loc_str = location.loc_name + ', ' + location.loc_detail
                else:
                    loc_str = location.loc_name

            db.session.add(location)
            db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for('location'))

        except IntegrityError:
            logging.error("edit_location(): Intg Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
            db.session.rollback()
            flash('Location (' + loc_str + ') already exists.', 'error')

        except DatabaseError:
            logging.error("edit_location(): DB Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
            db.session.rollback()
        except Exception as e:
            flash('Error in form, site administrators have been notified. We apologize for the inconvenience.', 'error')
            logging.error("edit_location(): Exception occurred", exc_info=True)

    return render_template('edit_location.html', title=title_sub + " Location", loc_id=loc_id, form=form)
```

1. Changed parameter from `string:loc_id` to `int:loc_id`, and updated related if statements
2. Added explicit if request.method `== "GET"` to ensure your recommendation, `form = LocationForm(request.form)`, did not run during POST calls where the form was already populated
3. Set location values in POST based on `loc_id == 0`, either from Location or form
4. Finally, included `db.session.add()` and `db.session.commit()`.

Thanks, again!